# QGIS - quickly style categorical map

Tags: qgis, raster, style

Example situation: a raster map that denotes various provinces in a country, each indicated with a unique value.

Goal/question: quickly (for 'preview' purposes, not making a publishable map) assign different colors to each value in the map. So not along a gradient. How do I do that?

Background: in previous versions of QGIS (pre-2.4? maybe pre-2.0?) you could set 'render type' to 'singleband pseudocolor' and, IIRC, the default behaviour was to load the list with value/color mapping from the data (i.e., if there are 10 unique values, put those in the list) and assign random colors to them. Which is perfect (well, 'good enough', 4-color theorem and all) for my purposes.

However, in recent versions of QGIS it seems I can only use the 'generate new color' on the right. Which only does gradients. Furthermore, I can't seem to automatically load the values in the map into the value/color list. 'Load color map from band' only works on data formats that explicitly support 'embedded legends', so to say.

So, is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: When you select "Singleband pseudocolor" for the render type, the second to last entry in the dropdown list in the "Generate new colormap" section is "Random colors". Is that what you're looking for? For loading the values into the value/color list, you can set "Equal interval" for the mode and then use the "Classify" button.

Comment: Thanks, I has missed the 'random colors' which indeed is much better than a gradient. But when I use "Equal interval", I still need to manually enter the number of unique values in the "classes" field, as well as set "min" and "max"? Plus that wouldn't account for missing values (e.g. 0, 2, 4, 5)?

Comment: You don't need to set `Min` and `Max` manually: you can select "Min / max" in the "Load min/max of full extent" section and "Actual (slower)" in the "Accuracy" section, then click "Load". You do need to set the number of classes manually (it's `max - min + 1`). I'm not sure what you mean by "Plus that wouldn't account for missing values (e.g. 0, 2, 4, 5)?"